# Having troouble using psycopg2 execute_values() correctly

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm having trouble using the execute_values() option correctly.  I am getting a "Failed to insert record into dist_crt_opins table not all arguments converted during string formatting".

My code grabs data for all district courts in the US and I have created a list called "data" for the items I am scraping.  Here is the relevant code for the insert:

```
data = []
results = (court,case_title,issue_date,link,details)
print(results)
data.append(results)

for d in data:
    sql = '''INSERT INTO dist_crt_opins (court, case_title, issue_date, link, details) VALUES (%s),'''
    psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor,sql,d, template='(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', page_size=1000)
    conn.commit()
```

I have successfully inserted the same data with a simple row by row insert statement, but I was looking for a faster way as there are ~100,000 rows to enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I didn't have to do a for loop to iterate over the rows.  And there was an error in the insert statement.

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO dist_crt_opins (court, case_title, issue_date, link, details) VALUES (%s),'''

should be no parentheses around the placeholder "%s":

sql = "INSERT INTO dist_crt_opins (court, case_title, issue_date, link, details) VALUES %s;"
psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor,sql,data,template=None, page_size=1000)
```